# Что значит знак "!" в typescript/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Заметил знак "!" в одном из шаблонов после `document.getElementById('root')`, он убрал ошибку типа аргумента у метода. Что данный знак делает и допустимо ли его использование?

```typescript
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

Comment: Этот знак информирует typescript, что переменная после которой он стоит будет точно не null, или undefined, то есть ТОЧНО (вы даете гарантию) будет ссылаться на валидное значение соответствующего типа. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions

Comment: А допустимо ли его использование или лучше избегать?

Comment: если бы использование было недопустимо, компилятор бы давал ошибку при использовании